# Kitchen drain not downward sloping. fix or leave alone

Tags: drain, kitchen-sink

Just a quick question. I'm living in a new place and getting familiar with the property. I was going to reinstall a new sink drain as well as a multi stage RO filter when I noticed after the p-trap that there's a positive grade. There hasn't been any problems and I haven't heard any complaints but could this be problematic and would you correct this, and how?

There's play in the drain pipe itself. It's just settled down and I can hoist and support it higher at the point it enters the drywall, but that will only transfer the problem upstream, which I suppose could be worse in terms of backflow risk. It seems to me as long as the p trap exit point is lower than entry point of the main vertical drain on the rear left, there will have to be some uphill grade, and changing that out is definitely above my pay grade. Enough water volume and resultant pressure will force the water through an uphill grade, but with the p-trap it's a column. That seems healthier than a horizontal line of water the length of a section, and I imagine food sitting there. I'm going to flush the sinks once a week or so, as recommended by a plumber on YouTube, but still is this something that can and should be addressed, or am I just really overthinking it? Thanks much

Ps maybe there's a more vertically rising part on the output side of the p. Like I said it seems better to get the grade from vertical rise vs horizontal gradual, though I can't explain my intuition on that. Actually yes I can, the water is a defense, in one solid block, all or nothing unless it's pushed over the edge, vs spread thin.

[image: sink drain]

Comment: since you know all the answers, is the a question for us ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd swap the p-trap to the other side.  The slope will be easier to make.  Your dishwasher drain line looks like it will be long enough.  You want 1/4" slope per foot or your trap will siphon.  In your current scenario your p-trap is going to fill with food particles and be prone to clogging.

You can do as you say and just flush it all the time but that's a pain and it shouldn't be too hard to adjust.

Comment: also you want your dwash drain line to run up high and then come down for an air gap.  right now looks like an easy backup into your dishwasher

Comment: Would the pipe section between the tee and trap be able to be shorten?  It seems about an inch shorter might fix the the slope.

Comment: D/W also needs a high loop...